# backbone fetch specific object from json file, not rendering

Tags: json, parsing, backbone.js, fetch

Okay, im going slightly insane trying to display data from a json file in 2 seperate views/collections.

I will paste my entire code here and try to explain where i am now, and what i need done.
Its probably a very small thing i just need to do in order for it to work, but i cant see it..

Here is a screen shot of how my page looks like now, as you can see the data is being loaded, i just cant get it into the views properly..

[image]

In my Collection class i call parse:

```
parse:function(response, options) {
   return options.parseField ? response[options.parseField] : response;
},
```

i call sync: (not sure its needed at all)

```
sync: function(method, model, options) {
options.contentType = "application/json";
options.cache = false;
options.dataType = "json";
return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
},
```

Then near the bottom, i create 2 new collections and use fetch to get the specific json data i need for each collection like so:

```
var links = new App.Collections.Links();
links.fetch({
  parseField: 'links_1',
  success: function () {
    console.log(links.toJSON());
            return links.toJSON();
  }
});

var links2 = new App.Collections.Links();
links2.fetch({
  parseField: 'links_2',
  success: function () {
    console.log(links2.toJSON());
            return links2.toJSON();
  }
});
```

I do console.log and can see that my json data is getting loaded just fine, but its not getting rendered ?

What am i doing wrong here..

For sake of debugging and understanding i have included my entire js file below.

```
(function() {

// Helper functions

// Defining namespacing rules
window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {}
};

// Setting global template function, for simpel declaration later on by setting template('name'); for the built in template function.
window.template = function(id) {
    return _.template( $('.' + id).html() );
};


// Capitalize first letter in a link by adding .capitalize(); to the string.
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};

// Extending Backbone 

//Modellen
App.Models.Link = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        navn : 'i haz a name!',
        link : 'http://www.lolcats.com/',
        counter : 0
    }
});


//Collection
App.Collections.Links = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 

    model: App.Models.Link,
    url: 'data1.json',

    parse:function(response, options) {
        return options.parseField ? response[options.parseField] : response;
    },

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.cache = false;
        options.dataType = "json";
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    },

    // Sort the models 'highest first'
    comparator: function(link) {
    return -link.get('counter');
    }       
});


//Singel view
App.Views.LinkView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagnavn: 'li',

    template: template('Links'),

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },

    events: {
    'click .edit' : 'retLink',
    'click .delete' : 'destroy',
    'click .LinkUrl' : 'addCounter'
    },

    retLink: function() {
        var newLinkNavn = prompt('What should the new name be?', this.model.get('navn'));

        if ( !newLinkNavn ) return;

        newLinkNavn = newLinkNavn.capitalize();
        this.model.set('navn', newLinkNavn);


        var newLinkUrl = prompt('What should the new url be?', this.model.get('link'));
        if ( !newLinkUrl ) return;
        this.model.set('link', newLinkUrl);
    },      

    destroy: function() {
        this.model.destroy();

    },

    // Increment the counter then user clicks it
    addCounter: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newCounter = this.model.get('counter');
        this.model.set('counter', newCounter + 1);
    },

    remove: function() {
        this.$el.remove();
    },

    render: function()  {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
        return this;
    }
});

//Collection View
App.Views.LinksView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'liste',

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render);

        // Render view when a user has changed a model          
        this.collection.bind('change', this.render, this); 

        $('.navnClass').focus();
        this.load();
        this.render();

    },

    load: function() {
        this.collection.fetch({
          add: true,
          success: this.loadCompleteHandler,
          error: this.errorHandler
        });     
    },

    loadCompleteHandler : function(){
        this.render();
    },

    errorHandler : function(){
        throw "Error loading JSON file";
    },

    render: function() {
        // Empty the UL before populating it with the new models and sorting it.
        this.$el.empty();
        this.collection.sort();

        this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
        return this;
    },

    addOne: function(link) {
        var linkView = new App.Views.LinkView({ model: link });
        this.$el.append(linkView.render().el);
    }
});

// Create link view 
App.Views.AddLink = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#addLink',

    events: {
        'submit' : 'submit'
    },

    submit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var linkNavn = $(e.currentTarget).find('.navnClass').val(),
             linkNum =  $(e.currentTarget).find('.linkClass').val();



        // Tildel link navn en værdi, hvis det er tomt   
        if ( ! $.trim(linkNavn)) {
                linkNavn = 'I haz a name!';
        }

        // Tildel link url en værdi, hvis det er tomt    
        if( ! $.trim(linkNum)) {
                linkNum = 'http://www.lolcats.com/';
        }

        // Tilføj http:// foran værdi, hvis den ikke indeholder det i forvejen.
        if( linkNum.indexOf( "http://" ) == -1 ) {
             addedValue = 'http://',
             linkNum = addedValue + linkNum;
        }

        // nulstil og sæt fokus på link navn feltet.
        $(e.currentTarget).find('.navnClass').val('').focus();
        $(e.currentTarget).find('.linkClass').val('');
        this.collection.add({ navn:linkNavn, link: linkNum });
    }

});


// new links collection
// populate collection from external JSON file
// change navn to match the link heading

var links = new App.Collections.Links();
links.fetch({
  parseField: 'links_1',
  success: function () {
    console.log(links.toJSON());
            return links.toJSON();
  }
});

var links2 = new App.Collections.Links();
links2.fetch({
  parseField: 'links_2',
  success: function () {
    console.log(links2.toJSON());
            return links2.toJSON();
  }
}); 


// new collection view (add)
var addLinkView = new App.Views.AddLink({ collection: links });

// new collection view
var linksView = new App.Views.LinksView({ collection: links });
$('.links').html(linksView.el);

// new collection view
var linksView2 = new App.Views.LinksView({ collection: links2 });
$('.links2').html(linksView2.el);   


})();
```

Comment: can you tell me what does your application do in general ?

Comment: It just shows some links with corrosponding names, but there are X number of link containers, that needs to be populated with links from 1 json file, that is why i want to be able to fetch only specific json data for each "link container".

The links then sort after the number of times they have been clicked. that is why i have the counter and the sort method.

Comment: just to clarify @Marcel , when you enter the name in the textbox and click add , the link should be displayed at 2 places at the same time and then , depending on the number of clicks , you want to sort links at respective places

Comment: No, you can disregard the add new link functionality.
Im talking about on page load, i have a json file that gets loaded into the 2 link containers, one part (links_1) should get loaded into the first collection/view. the second part (links_2) should get loaded into the second collection/view. It is allready created in the app. And the json data also gets loaded, as you can see in my attached screenshot. in the console. I just cant figure out how to render the data in the 2 views..

Comment: The "i haz a name" links are the two objects that are being loaded, each representing a collection, i need to extract and show the array data instead of the object... in the console on the screenshot you can see that each object contains a number of links and names.. those are the data i want to get displayed instead of the 2 "i haz a name" objects.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
var links2 = new App.Collections.Links();
links2.on("reset", function(collection){
   console.log("reset event", collection);
}
links2.fetch({
  parseField: 'links_2',
  wait:true, #wait for the server to respond
  success: function (collection, response) {
    console.log(collection, response);
  }
});
```

a return in the success call doesn't do anything (it would return to the $.ajax object). I've added a wait because it would call the successcall instantly if it passes the clientside validation (you have none, so it would always call success first).

You say it doesn't render anything. But to render something you need a View. I don't see a view in your code.

Here's a quick example of the view:

```
var Link = new Backbone.View.extends({
    el: $('body'),
    initialize: function(){
       this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render, this)
    },
    render: function(){
     this.$el.empty();
     this.collection.each(function(item){
        this.$el.append(item.get('id') + '<br />');
     });

    }
})
var view = new Link({collection: links2});
```

Comment: Hi André, i have 2 views in my code - one for the item and one for the collection. you just have to scroll down to the part where i have pasted my entire js file.

Your code does exactly the same, my code did - it returns the object "links_2" instead of the data inside the "links_2" array.